# Bootstrap carousel : Get interval via jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, carousel

It's possible to set the interval for a Boostrap carousel in jQuery with this code:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({  interval: 1000 * 10  });
```

My question is:

How can I get the interval?

My intention is to start the carousel with the default interval, and to slow it down after each transition.
That way people say right away there is a slide show, but have more and more time to read the captions as the slideshow slows down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change carousel options after start. Here is a simple example that will reduce speed by half on each cycle, by doubling the interval option.

```
var carousel = $('.carousel');
var slides = carousel.find(".item").length;
carousel.carousel({ interval: 1000 });

var slowDown = function() {
    var options = carousel.data()['bs.carousel'].options;
    options.interval = options.interval * 2;
    carousel.data({ options: options });
    console.log(options.interval);
}

carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index() + 1;

    if (slideFrom === slides) {
        slowDown();
    }        
});
```

Comment: Your code worked to get the interval. Thanks.  I added a line to make it pause 20 seconds on a mouse over: $('#carousel').one('mousemove', function() { $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 1000 * 20}); } );  It did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using my plugin or Bootstrap carousel: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-carousel

It wraps the carousel plugin in a more readable way. There, set the interval with:

```
$('.carousel'). bCarousel({'interval': 1000});
```